# PostgreSQL JSONB find documents by word

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table of the form:

```
                          Table "public.items"
     Column      |           Type           |         Modifiers         
-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------
 item_id         | character varying        | not null
 content         | character varying        | 
 tags            | jsonb                    | 
 body            | jsonb                    |
```

The **body** field contains data like these:

```
[{"text": "As a child home ..."}, 
{"text": "Great post. Watch this }]
```

What query is needed to find documents by word in the **text** section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard (and most adequate) approach is the one provided by @Dan in the other answer, namely to treat a jsonb column as such an parse it using the operators `->` and `->>`.

An alternative to that would be to cast the column to text and go from there, e.g. `body::text`:

```
SELECT * FROM public.items WHERE body::TEXT LIKE '%child%';
SELECT * FROM public.items WHERE body::TEXT SIMILAR TO '%child%';
```

In case you don't want it to be case sensitive, convert both strings before comparing them, for instance using `LOWER` or `UPPER` (see [**documentation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)):

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE LOWER(body::TEXT) LIKE LOWER('%CHILD%');
```

As suggested by Dan in the comments, `ILIKE` is another elegant way for dealing case insensitive queries:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE body::TEXT ILIKE '%child%'
```

**Note**: both approaches rely on a proper index to work satisfactory, otherwise the query might get very slow. See this other answer with a [`GIN index`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68576171/2275388)

Comment: For case insensitive it's better to use `ILIKE` instead of using a function for every sentence.

Comment: Also, you can access a JSON attribute directly without having to cast it at text. See my answer.

Comment: you're right, I totally forgot ILIKE.. thanks for the kind message. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the seach using jsonb functions.
Lets say you have this:

```
item_id | body
--------+---------------------------------------------------------------
1       | [{"text":"aSdf aSdf"},{"text":"12 41f"},{"text":"1 31s sf"}]
2       | [{"text":"31fa3"},{"text":"3f43f"}]
3       | [{"text":"l8412"},{"text":"52%$3d1f"},{"text":"agasd as3"}]
4       | [{"text":"i8i23"}]
```

You can search for every element in your jsonb using:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT t.id,elem.*
FROM public.items t,jsonb_array_elements(t.body) AS elem)json_vals
WHERE value->>'text' ILIKE '%s%'
```

This will return the next result because the query uses `ILIKE`:

```
item_id | value
--------+----------------------
1       | {"text":"aSdf aSdf"}
1       | {"text":"1 31s sf"}
3       | {"text":"agasd as3"}
```

If you just need the id, you can change the `*` in the query for `item_id` and use `DISTINCT`. But with this query you can access every JSON in the record without having to cast it as `text`.

**NOTE:** if you just query `SELECT t.id,elem.* FROM public.items t,jsonb_array_elements(t.body) AS elem` you get every element in a row:

```
itme_id | value
--------+--------------------
1       | {"text":"aSdf aSdf"}
1       | {"text":"12 41f"}
1       | {"text":"1 31s sf"}
2       | {"text":"31fa3"}
2       | {"text":"3f43f"}
3       | {"text":"l8412"}
3       | {"text":"52%$3d1f"}
3       | {"text":"agasd as3"}
4       | {"text":"i8i23"}
```

Comment: I have a correction: The **body** field looks like this: [{"text": "As a child home ..."}, 
    {"text": "Great post. Watch this }]

Comment: Updated my answer according to your changes.

Comment: I'm got the error: ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar

Comment: With my test table works just fine. Are you shure your JSON is built as you said? Perhaps In your data there is some scalar value instead of an array inside.